# How do I get a list of unit tests in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I am using deftest to define some unit tests (the tests are generated by a macro, which is why the identifiers are fully qualified):

```
   (clojure.test/deftest
      init-globals-test
        (clojure.test/is (clojure.core/= 40 casc-gen-org.dev/*board-width*))
        (clojure.test/is (clojure.core/= 40 casc-gen-org.dev/*board-height*)))
```

However when I run the tests:

```
(run-tests)
```

I get the following:

```
: #'casc-gen-org.dev/clj-run-runtime-uts{:type :summary, :fail 0, :error 0, :pass 6, :test 3}
```

It says I have 3 tests and 6 assertions (assuming I'm reading this right), but I only expected 1 test and 2 assertions.  I assume I have some stale tests in my repl somwhere and I'd like to delete them.

I looked at the doc for deftest (https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.test-api.html) and don't see anything related to listing tests.

How do I list the tests that are currently defined?

Comment: What clojure.test does is it goes through every defined ns with `all-ns` and then goes through every var in each ns with `ns-interns`, running the ones with a `:test` key in the metadata. There may or may not be a more elegant way to handle this.

Comment: At least now I know it's not something trivial, so I'll stop trying to look for a simple command.  Seems pretty amazing that's there isn't some easy way to do this though.

Comment: `(->> (all-ns) (map ns-publics) (mapcat vals) (filter (comp :test meta)))` works, is it worth making an answer out of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clojure.test` does a manual search / filter to find vars with the `:test` metadata, and all vars found with that metadata key are considered tests. We can do the same, and list the vars that will be considered unit tests with a small function of no arguments:

```
#(->> (all-ns)
      (mapcat (comp vals ns-interns))
      (filter (comp :test meta)))
```